# How to add a column in each CSV file (read through For Loop) with a constant numeric value in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am reading multiple CSV files and performing some operations on it using the following code:

```
delta=50
# For High1 treatment

H1 <- c(21,22,29,30,34,65,66,69,70,74)   # listing numbers corresponding to csv files
F <- list()                               # initializing the list

for(i in H1) {                            # Loop over character vector
  F[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0("F:/Fish",i,"/Fish", i, ".csv"))
  F[[i]]$fishspeed[1] <- 0 #assigning 0 as the starting fish speed
  F[[i]]$distance <- NA #create the distance column

  for (j in 2:nrow(F[[i]])) {
    #calculating distance from distance formula (both in x and y)
    F[[i]]$distance[j] <- sqrt((F[[i]]$X..cm.[j]-F[[i]]$X..cm.[j-1])^2 + (F[[i]]$Y..cm.[j]-F[[i]]$Y..cm.[j-1])^2)
    #calculating fish speed in x and y
    F[[i]]$fishspeed[j] <- F[[i]]$distance[j]/(0.02)
    #assigning positive and negative signs to the velocity 
    F[[i]]$fishspeed[j] <- ifelse(F[[i]]$X..cm.[j]-F[[i]]$X..cm.[j-1] < 0,F[[i]]$fishspeed[j],-F[[i]]$fishspeed[j])
  }
  
  F[[i]] <- F[[i]] %>% 
    group_by(frame = rep(row_number(), each=delta, length.out = n())) %>% 
    mutate(speed = ifelse(fishspeed== "#VALUE!", NA, fishspeed)) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(Speed = median(fishspeed, na.rm = TRUE))

}
```

As of now, the current output I am getting is a list with multiple data frames and each data frame with 2 columns.

I would like to add another new column named "Class" to each of the data frames in the list. However, I want a sequential numeric value for that column based on each CSV file.

So, for example, for the first data frame, all the rows in the "Class" column should contain the numeric value of 1. Then for the next data frame with a numeric value of 2 in each of its rows in the "Class" column and subsequently for the next data frames 3, 4, 5, and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `F[[i]]["Class"] <- i`

Comment: SamR's is close, but the first CSV file processed in this example would be assigned `21` instead of `1`. Instead, you could do `F[[i]]["Class"] <- match(i, H1)`. Alternatively, one could do this after completing your existing `for` loop: `F  <- Map(function(x, i) { x$Class <- i; x; }, F, seq_along(F))`. (BTW, naming a variable the same as the abbreviated version of `FALSE` is making my fingers hurt writing that code ... perhaps choose another letter? Please not one of R's pre-defined single letter funcs: `C`, `D`, `F`, `c`, `q`, or `t` :-)

Comment: @r2evans Could you please help me in solving this plotting issue if you know how it could be done? I posted this question 2 days ago but couldn't find an answer yet. Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740886/adding-custom-legend-in-ggplot-for-lines-drawn-using-geom-abline